# Use regular Google accounts as application-owned accounts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api

I wan't to use regular Google accounts as application-owned accounts.
At first, I tried to use service account but I cannot buy additional storage while using this account.
Then I saw this option on Google documentation:

```
Use regular Google accounts as application-owned accounts
```

How can I implement this log-in method in Java?
Please Advice,
Noam

Answer (score 1):

Create a new account [1] and go through the OAuth 2.0 Web flow [1].

[1] https://accounts.google.com/SignUp

[2] https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server